# Displaying variable Prices in a Shop Menu

Tags: e-commerce, user-expectation, price-range

I am redesigning a **shopping experience for food delivery**, and I have come across this situation where I want to display the price of an item inside the menu, but **Price may vary** depending on specific parameters. Let's take for an example a Pizza item, that can vary greatly because of the size, type of crust etc.

Up until now, **the previous design showed this with a '+' sign next to the price.** However, I'm afraid this makes the design too noisy by putting 2 symbols so close (the Currency Sign and the '+' sign. Also, I'm not sure it is really clear to the user.

When clicking on the price/button (as seen on the mockup below), a popup opens displaying all the available options. The user makes his choices and adds the item to his cart.

*Note: By national convention, the currency is displayed at the right of the price, not at the left.*

- One option is to completely ditch the symbol, simply displaying the
  lowest possible price. This has the obvious problem that the user
  could see a low price and then come up with something completely
  different inside the popup.
- Another option would be to display min and max price. This is really
  the most informative but it overloads the design and makes it even
  noisier.
- A more clever option (but still taking too much space) would be to add a "From: " label somewhere near
  the starting price, to avoid confusion afterwards.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNhuAz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

What would be your opinion on this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Either of the last two are fairly clear.  But the "plus" sign model does not clearly show that the prices could be higher.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm leaning towards the 'From' approach, cause of the clutterless design.

Comment: I also personally prefer the 'From', as I also think it is clearest and cleanest, but you could certainly make either one work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be clear about the price and at the same time keep the design clean, you may try the following design. You can put all the item type as a button on the main menu, and then showing the size or different parameters with price tags in the second step. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is indeed a nice approach that could remove confusion. Unfortunately the website is an ordering platform for multiple restaurants, so the variable items differ a lot from restaurant to restaurant. One could have 3 variations while another (let's say a pizza) could have 20-50 variations, that can't be shown on the menu all at once. This could be used however for standarized items, e.g. Soda's and Drinks!

Comment: I am wondering how is it working now since you said there can be up to 50 variations. People need to see all these 50 options before they buy, right? I am curious that how do all these items get displayed now?

Comment: All base items are displayed in the menu as shown above. When the user clicks on an item, a popup loads with all the details (photo, description) and options. For an average Pizza, there would be several rows of fieldsets (size, crust, ingredients). The variations are not static but rather dynamic, so we don't get to display all 50 options (There is no option "Pizza Marguerita Small Thin Crust", but the user could create such an item through separate options). After making the selections, the user can Add the item to Cart through a Button at the bottom of the Popup.